# How do I run a remote PHP script then follow a link from HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

****THIS IS AN UPDATE!!! ORIGINAL POST IS DOWN BELOW.****

From the answers provided I've now changed the code a little. Now I have this....

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>

<script>
var coinToss = Math.random();

function runScript()

{

if (coinToss >= 0.5) {
$.get( "http://splittestpro.com/splittestonepage.php?test=1&member=4&result=1" );
}
else
{
$.get( "http://splittestpro.com/splittestonepage.php?test=1&member=4&result=2" );

}  

}
</script>
```

And this is my onclick command in my link.

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/order.html" onclick="runScript();">click here</a>
```

This code follows the link but it does not run the code. However, if I change the href to href="#" it does run the code, but not follow the link. So the same as before!!!

The suggestion given in one of the answers is to have the redirect inside the function. But this is code that is going into other peoples websites. So the onclick to activate the function could be on a form submit button, or a link, or an image or on whatever they want to track and I don't know the URL they are linking to with the click (They might not want to link to a URL at all!)

Is there any way I can tweak this code so that it forces the $.get command to run the PHP script before it triggers the link? I thought that this happened automatically using an onclick inside a link.

I've also tried $.post in place of $.get but that's not working either.

Thanks for your help

****ORIGINAL POST BELOW HERE******

The script I need to run is a PHP script on another server. I do not need any information back from the script at all, I just need it to run when a person clicks on a link, then to follow the link.

This code is not for my own site, I am providing it to members, so the page must be basic HTML code, I know I can do this from a PHP page but I need it to work from HTML and Javascript.

What I'm doing now...

At the moment I'm using innerHTML to change a DIV tag inside a javascript function like this...

```
function runScript()
{
document.getElementById('thetrigger').innerHTML = "<img src='http://splittestpro.com/splittestonepage.php?test=1&member=4&result=2' style='height: 1px; width: 1px; visibility: hidden;' />";
}
```

With this DIV tag on the page....

```
<div id="thetrigger"></div>
```

I am using an onclick command to trigger the function like this...

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/order.html" onclick="runScript();">click here to order</a>
```

What I've tried...

- If I run the script without the link the PHP executes fine, so I know the PHP is all OK
- If I add 'return false' into the link the PHP works as I would expect it to
- I have tried various combinations of return false and return true, as well as using onclick="return runScript();" then having return true inside the function.
- I've tried lots of ways to do this but everything I try either will not run the PHP code but will follow the link, OR it does run the code but it doesn't follow the link

PLEASE NOTE....

My main problem is that I am in a basic HTML page using Javascript and I want to run a PHP script that's on another server. None of that can change, so please don't offer solutions that involve changing the page to a PHP page. The page is not mine, I'm giving this code to members of my business, and their pages are basic HTML pages.

Also... Please note that I don't need any data back from the PHP script. It only needs to make the script run then follow the link.

A POSSIBLE SOLUTION....

At the moment I'm triggering the PHP script by having it hidden in an IMG tag that is inserted into a DIV on the page.

I have searched for alternative ways to run a remote PHP script from javascript and can't find any solutions that work.

I imagine my solution should be something like this....

```
<script>
function runScript()
{
**RUN PHP SCRIPT**
}
</script>

<a href="http://yoursite.com/order.html" onclick="runScript(); return true;">click here to order</a>
```

BUT.... what do I put in the **RUN PHP SCRIPT** section?

It seems that using AJAX or cURL might be a possible way to do this. I have no idea about that though, so would need it explaining. Also, if I use AJAX will it work fine inside a basic HTML page.

I want to give my members the code without them having to change or add anything on their server etc. They should be able to just copy and paste the code snippet into their basic HTML page.

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use AJAX. That way your PHP script will be run "in the background" and you'll be able to redirect your user to a new page on success. Below is a simple jQuery example.

```
<script>
function runScript() {
  $.get( "file.php", function() {
    window.location = "http://www.pagetoredirectto.com/"
  });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried this but it's still doing the same. It has made my code neater though :)

The trouble is I can't put the window.location into the function as it's code I'm asking people to copy into their website. They might be adding it to a link, or a button or an image or where ever they want to track a click. So I don't know where to redirect people to after the function. 

When I replace the URL in the href to # it works exactly like I want it to but it doesn't follow the link. And if I have the website in it follows the link but doesn't run the script.

Comment: I've just tried the code exactly as you've included it here with the window.location inside the function and I still get the same result. It does not run the script it only follows the link. If I add return false; it runs the script but doesn't follow the link. So still exactly the same result every way I've tested. Any suggestions? I'm pulling my hair out!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest learning AJAX. This will allow you to send a request when the button is clicked, then when the request completes you can relocate the browser to wherever you want.

Your problem is likely that both the PHP script and the relocate are trying to happen at the same time, so only one of them is succeeding.

AJAX is pretty easy to learn, just Google it or check out [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) tutorial on it.

Comment: I'm on there right now :) Definitely making my code much neater but I still have the same problem. I've updated my post to show where I'm at now.